# Is there something wrong with floatingFilter in reagent?

Tags: ag-grid, clojurescript, reagent

I pass floatingFilter as a parameter to agGridReact and setting it to true in defaultColDef but it does not work. Does someone know what is wrong?

```
:defaultColDef {:sortable true
                :editable true
                :width deafult-col-w
                :filter true
                :floatingFilter true}
```

These are my dependencies:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.339"]
                 [reagent "0.8.1"]
                 [cljsjs/ag-grid-react "21.0.1-1"]
                 [cljsjs/ag-grid-community "21.0.1-1"]]
```

This is the result of my code. Note that I want a row under the columndefinitions, that allows the user to filter.
[image: Result of ag-grid]

Comment: "does not work" - what exactly?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, and it doesn't show in the rendered result, I have added a picture in the question.